# jQuery - has children without ANY class (not specific class)

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, guys, basically what I need to find:

----> All `<li>` which has `<ul>` without ANY class.

In this example I would ONLY want the `<li>` parent of the commented `<ul>`:

HTML

```
<ul id="myList">
    <li>
        <a>Item 1</a>
        <ul class="someClass">

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>    <!--------- Just Need This One ---------->
        <a>Item 2</a>
        <ul>

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Item 3</a>
        <ul class="justAnotherClass">

        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm aware of `.not("[class]")`, and so I tried something like:

```
$('#myList li').has('ul').not("[class]")
```

which obviously doesn't work because jQuery is looking for `<li>`'s which have a nested `<ul>` but doesn't have any class.

So, guys, can anyone please help? :)

Comment: Try using jquery's filter... `$('#myList li ul').filter(':not([class])')`

Comment: I'm trying to affect the `<li>`, not the `<ul>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using

```
$('#myList li').has('ul').not("[class]")
```

you can use

```
$('#myList > li').has('ul:not([class])')
```

you can also use this selector

```
$('#myList > li:has(ul:not([class]))')
```

```js
$('#myList > li:has(ul:not([class]))').css('background' , 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myList">
    <li>
        <a>Item 1</a>
        <ul class="someClass">

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Item 2</a>
        <ul>    <!--------- Just Need This One ---------->
        
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Item 3</a>
        <ul class="justAnotherClass">
        
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm trying to affect the `<li>`, not the `<ul>`

Comment: Does this has any incompatibility with jQuery 1.11.3? Because it's returning all the `<li>`'s anyway
EDIT: it seems I need v1.4, right?

Comment: @jbarradas its not related with jquery version .. what do you mean with returning <li>'s .. its already works fine on snippet

Comment: sorry, you're right, nothing to do with version. But as you can see in the following jsfiddle, it's not affecting only `<li>`'s which have `<ul>`'s without classnames. Where am I failing? https://jsfiddle.net/ekfextwk/1/

Comment: @jbarradas your problem in a selector  by using '.treeview  li'  it will select all the li's inside .treeview element .. so you need to use .treeview > li  to select the direct li to treeview element like this https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/ekfextwk/2/  ... or use .treeview > li > ul > li  to select the second one like this https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/ekfextwk/3/  and so on

Comment: @jbarradas also you can use something like this https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/ekfextwk/4/

Comment: awesome! that solution works perfect for me :) thanks!

Comment: @jbarradas you'r Welcome .. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter()` over `li` and then check for children `ul` without any `class` with `.length`,

```
$('#myList li').filter(function(){
    return $('ul:not([class])',this).length > 0    //$('child','context') selector
    //or $('> ul:not([class])',this) in case of direct <ul>
});
```

```js
var $li = $('#myList li').filter(function(){
    return $('ul:not([class])',this).length > 0    //$('child','context') selector
});

console.log($li)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myList">
    <li>
        <a>Item 1</a>
        <ul class="someClass">

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Item 2</a>
        <ul>    <!--------- Just Need This One ---------->

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Item 3</a>
        <ul class="justAnotherClass">

        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's almost this, but it's still returning me all the `<ul>`s, maybe something with :not() ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('#myList li ul').filter(':not([class])')`:

```js
console.log($('#myList li ul').filter(':not([class])').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myList">
    <li>
        <a>Item 1</a>
        <ul class="someClass">

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Item 2</a>
        <ul>    <!--------- Just Need This One ---------->

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Item 3</a>
        <ul class="justAnotherClass">

        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm trying to affect the `<li>`, not the `<ul>`

Answer (score 0):

I really hate that 'too short to be an answer' ....

```
$('#myList li > ul:not([class])')
```

Seems to be the simplest one that does the job ?